# SQL connection failure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a server with SQL Management Studio 2005 installed on a server 10.x.x.x as IP.

I also have a PC with SQL Management Studio 2005 Express installed.

The problem is that from my PC I can connect to the server successfully but I cannot to localhost even with Windows Authentication..

I tried to troubleshoot the problem but I couldn't find any SQL service in windows services.
also I don't know the credentials of the SQL specially that I was not asked to submit it during the SQL Management Studio 2005 Express Setup , any help please?

Comment: Have you installed any sql server instance in your local machine? It sounds like you have got just the `management studio not the server` in your local machine.

Comment: On which machine are you connecting to localhost?  Localhost is the machine you are currently on, so if SQL server is installed on your server, not your PC, you won't be able to use the name localhost, you will have to use the server name or IP.

Comment: If you don't find any service, then perhaps database engine wasn't installed, just client tools?

Comment: Do you have `SQL Server` or just `SQL Server Management Studio` installed? These are two separate products. First is a database engine that operates databases and can be connected to from various clients, applications, locations. `Management Studio` on the other hand is just a client tool/application used to access and browse databases which can be on same or different location. It seems that you are mixing the two, and that you have only SSMS on your PC (which is actually fine as you should be storing DB only on server and use PC just for browsing it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Management studio is just the tool to manage SQL databases. Hence the name. It is not the SQL Server itself.

If there's no SQL server service in services, chances are SQL Server is not installed.

Comment: On my local machine , there was not any SQL Server so I download it and install it and now I can manage it through the Management Studio Express.